# advantage of one dimensional array vs multidimensional array

Tags: functional-programming

memory arrangement of elements of arrays whether multidimensional or one dimensional is  consecutive(starting from first element.) Then what is the real need of multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1):

One use for a multidimensional array is that it forces all the sub-arrays to be the same size, and does it at the level of the type system, rather than enforcing it at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, multidimensional arrays "abstract away" the consecutiveness of memory. This allows the array to provide a more complex automated interface to the developer. In other words, it's just to make life easier for the developer in certain circumstances.

The underlying data will always be single-dimensional, but can be viewed as multidimensional to help the developer keep things organized.